# Amazon SP-API - ApluscontentV20201101Api - createContentDocument

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I want to create an Amazon A+ Content with the AplusContentV20201101Api like

here described: https://github.com/jlevers/selling-partner-api/blob/main/docs/Api/AplusContentV20201101Api.md

under "createContentDocument()"

I used the code example, the connection works, but my response looks like this:

> ```
> Exception when calling AplusContentV20201101Api->createContentDocument: [400] {   "errors": [
> {
>   "code": "InvalidInput",
>   "message": "The request is not valid, please check the inputs and try again.",
>   "details": "Request failed validation: createContentDocument.postContentDocumentRequest.contentDocument: may
> ```
>
> not be null"
> }   ] } []

which parameters must be passed? Does anyone have an example?